# CouchDB lounge patching

Tags: couchdb

Does anyone know how to patch and install couchdb-lounge on a Ubuntu box?

Project here:

http://github.com/tilgovi/couchdb-lounge

Now, I know there is a installation instructions provided here:

http://wiki.github.com/tilgovi/couchdb-lounge/buildinstructions

but it seems out-of-date. From there I see that you need to patch **one** file but on the src I saw that there are multiple patch files. If I patched them all on CouchDB 0.10.1 it will give me a syntax error.

So my questions are:

1. Which version of CouchDB should I patch with?
2. Which patches do I need to patch before getting it to work?

Thanks,

Comment: I guess no one uses this? Oh well...

Answer (score 1):

Check here: http://nakubu.com/post/23
I followed the instructions and they seemed to work.
Sorry it's a bit late :)

Comment: Thank you sluiper! I actually contacted the author and it turns out that you no longer need to patch CouchDB as of version 1.0. Now I haven't try running it yet, I solved my issues by getting a bigger harddrive. But I will look into it when I need to.